# Guardar estado de un fragment con Recyclerview

Tags: android, recyclerview

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Item,SandwichViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Item, SandwichViewHolder>(

                Item.class,
                R.layout.row,
                SandwichViewHolder.class,
                mDatabase
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(SandwichViewHolder viewHolder, Item model, int position) {

                final String sandwich_key = getRef(position).getKey();

                viewHolder.setTitulo(model.getNombreItem());
                viewHolder.setDescripcion(model.getDescripcionItem());
                viewHolder.setImagen(getContext(),model.getImagenItem());

                viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        mListener.onSandwichSeleccionado(sandwich_key);

                    }
                });

            }


        };

        mReciclerSandwich.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
```

Hola por favor necesito ayuda, he creado un `recyclerview` en fragmentos, cada uno tiene su recycler el problema es que al cambiar de fragment en el navigation drawer estos recycler vuelven a cargarse. mi pregunta es como puedo guardar el estado del fragment o la posicion del recycler para que no se este cargando?

Comment: Por favor, puedes añadir algo de código para ver que estas haciendo o alguna informacion mas porque asi es un poco ambiguo y es algo difícil de entender que estas haciendo y que quieres lograr. Gracias.

Comment: @curro ahi adjunte una parte del codigo, y lo que quiero es guardar el estado de ese fragment he leido sobre el onsaveInstanceState pero no hallo como guardar ese recycler

Comment: En concreto, y sin ver esa parte del codigo, me suena a que estas recreando siempre el fragment, es decir, siempre haces un new tuFragment() en vez de buscarlo en memoria si ya esta creado con el fragment manager y entonces cargarlo.

Comment: pues si en el menu del nav drawer tengo  if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor_fragment, new SandwichsFragment()).commit();     Como se busca en memoria? lo siento eso es lo que no sé

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veamos, puedes hacer algo así:

```
private void changeFragment(Fragment f, String tag) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag) == null) {
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frameContainer, f, tag);
    } else {
        f = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameContainer, f, tag);
    }
    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE).commit();
}
```

Y al llamar a ese metodo haces:

```
TuFragment f = new TuFragment();
changeFragment(f, "el_tag_que_quieras_asociar_a_tu_fragment");
```

Lo que logras asi es que si el fragment no esta creado aun, lo creas, pero si ya está creado y añadido al fragmentManager entonces lo busca y lo carga.

Pruebalo y me cuentas qué tal te va.

Saludos.

Comment: hola lo hice aunque toco cambiar el background del recyclerview porque se cargaba un recycler encima del otro pero ya esta muchisimas gracias, en este mismo caso sabes como guardar la posicion del recycler para cuando uno seleccione un item y abra otra activity pero al darle atras vuelva a la posicion donde estaba y no se ponga el recycler desde el inicio nuevamente?

Comment: Hola @JuanSolano. Ahi tienes que jugar con el onSaveInstances() para guardar el estado de la posicion y luego en el onCreate miras si el bundle que te llega tiene el valor que has guardado y en ese caso lo cargas y posicionas en recyclerview en ese valor.

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda, saludos